# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'selectedUser' not found on type bg.fmi.master.thesis.beans.ProfileBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

Do you have any idea why my app throws me this exception:

```
WARNING: /myProfile.xhtml @71,27 target="#{profileBean.selectedUser}": Property 'selectedUser' not found on type bg.fmi.master.thesis.beans.ProfileBean
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /myProfile.xhtml @71,27 target="#{profileBean.selectedUser}": Property 'selectedUser' not found on type bg.fmi.master.thesis.beans.ProfileBean
---
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'selectedUser' not found on type bg.fmi.master.thesis.beans.ProfileBean
```

When i have this property in my bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "profileBean")
public class ProfileBean implements Serializable {
    private TUser selectedUser = new TUser();

    public TUser getSelectedUser() {
        return selectedUser;
    }

    public void setSelectedUser(TUser selectedUser) {
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    }
```

The .xhtml code is this:

```
      <p:dataGrid var="user" value="#{profileBean.userList}">
                            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        ....
        <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Save changes" actionListener="#{profileBean.editUser()}" >
           <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileBean.selectedUser}" value="#{user}" />
        </p:commandButton>
  </p:dataGrid>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code looks okay. You're most likely not running the code you think you're running. That said, your environment seems to support EL 2.2. Why not just `action="#{profileBean.editUser(user)}"` instead of this listener mess?

Comment: It throws again exception: Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /myProfile.xhtml @73,53 action="#{profileBean.editUser(user)}": Method not found: bg.fmi.master.thesis.beans.ProfileBean@11e9862.editUser(bg.fmi.master.thesis.model.TUser). I edited my method too.In one of your post on similar question, was written that f:attribute may be used and I manage to make it working with this code <f:attribute name="profileBean.selectedUser" value="#{user}" /> but it is still unclear for me why it does not work in the other ways describe above.

Comment: You're most likely not running the code you think you're running.

Comment: How can i understand what exactly i am running?

Comment: Do you have other errors in the log except for this?

Comment: No, it is just this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a simple project based on your sample code.

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Save changes" actionListener="#{profileBean.editUser()}" >
       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileBean.selectedUser}" value="#{user}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

There was no such error as described. Your problem comes from other place. Remove unnecessary bits and try to isolate the problem. You could change the name of the property and see if the error reflects the new name. Make sure you don't have another bean with the same name.